# Join two tables that have mismatched data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having difficulty coming up with a query to accomplish joining two tables that have mismatched data.

I have two tables that share the same Item and Serial Number columns but hold different information that I need to join into one table. The problem is that the items sold in Table A don't match the items sold in Table B. What I need to do is line up the Location from Table B to the items that we still carry in Table A. Hopefully this helps illustrate:

```
Table A                            Table B

a.Item | a.Serial                  b.Item | b.Serial | b.Sold | b.Location | b.WHSerial
x45      36-0004                   x45      36-0001    No       Rack1Bin2    WH0044
x45      36-0005                   x45      36-0002    No       Rack1Bin2    WH0045
x45      36-0006                   x45      36-0003    No       Rack1Bin2    WH0046
x45      36-0007                   x45      36-0004    No       Rack1Bin3    WH0047
y11      55-0110                   x45      36-0005    No       Rack1Bin3    WH0048
y11      55-0111                   x45      36-0006    Yes      N/A          WH0049
y11      55-0112                   x45      36-0007    Yes      N/A          WH0050
                                   y11      55-0109    No       Rack33Bin5   WH0122
                                   y11      55-0110    No       Rack33Bin5   WH0123
                                   y11      55-0111    No       Rack33Bin5   WH0124
                                   y11      55-0112    Yes      N/A          WH0125
```

Desired Output

```
a.Item | a.Serial | b.Location | b.WHSerial
x45      36-0004    Rack1Bin3    WH0047
x45      36-0005    Rack1Bin3    WH0048
x45      36-0006    Rack1Bin2    WH0044
x45      36-0007    Rack1Bin2    WH0045
y11      55-0110    Rack33Bin5   WH0123
y11      55-0111    Rack33Bin5   WH0124
y11      55-0112    Rack33Bin5   WH0122
```

Table A is the master table and I need to marry locations to each serial number, but I can't join based on serial number because of this mismatch. To make it slightly more completed some items in Table B have more unsold Serial numbers than in Table A. Any extra unsold items in Table B can be ignored.

The logic for the output is that if the matching serial in Table B has a valid location (not N/A) then it is good, but if it doesn't, there are other "unused" serials that do have valid locations that I want to swap in. For example 36-0006 & 36-0007 in Table A are not sold but in Table B they are sold and have invalid locations. As you can see -0001 through -0003 in Table B have no match in Table A and have valid locations. I would like to use these locations for -0006 & -0007. The assignments for the unused serials from Table B to Table A can be random, but they need to stay unique (as in, don't use the same unused serial twice).

Along with b.Location there is a corresponding b.WHSerial that needs to be on the final output.

Comment: I dont understand the logic. Why dont appear `36-0002`  or `36-0007` on the Desire output?

Comment: Why appear 36-0003  No ?    .. seems an error  ..

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Oops! Yes that was an error. I edited to correct the Desired Output.

Comment: How `36-0006` or `36-0007` doesnt have `N/A`

Comment: now  have not sense ( 45    36-0006  No     Rack1Bin2) and (x45    36-0007  No     Rack1Bin3) these have no relation

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza N/A is just an invalid location because they're sold and I don't want those, I want only locations that don't have N/A to match up to Table A that shows as unsold.

Comment: Then your sample doesnt make sense. Or you need to explain what is the logic for `36-0006 - Rack1Bin2`  or  `36-0004 - Rack1Bin2`

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I edited to add what the output logic is, I hope that helps clarify a bit. I was trying to show that the relationship in Table B of the Serial and Location isn't important, only that each unsold Serial in Table A  can be joined with a valid Location (not N/A) from Table B.

Comment: You say logic doesnt matter? so location can be `McDonald` ? Also will help if on desire result you indicate if field is from table A or table B

Comment: How come `36-0004` doesnt have `Rack1Bin3`, and how you choose the location for `36-0007`? random?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Okay, after reviewing my dataset I've updated my example to be a little more accurate. The Sold items in Table A actually get deleted. I originally didn't have the -0004 at Rack1Bin3 to show that it's okay if they no longer match, but if it's easier they can, so I've updated my example and logic explanation to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/UFCQJ70688)**

First you calculate what locations are unused and assign a row_number. Then you find what serial have a matching location, and those who doesnt you also assign a row_number. Finally join both together. So unused location are only used once because are matching rn.

```
WITH unusedLocation AS (
    SELECT B.[Item], B.[Serial], B.[Sold], B.[Location], A.[Serial] as [code],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.[Item] ORDER BY B.[Location]) as rn
    FROM [TableB] B
    LEFT JOIN [TableA] A
    ON  A.[Item] = B.[Item]
    AND A.[Serial] = B.[Serial]    
    WHERE B.Location <> 'N/A'
      AND A.[Serial] IS NULL
), matchLocation AS (      
    SELECT A.[Item], A.[Serial], B.[Location],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.[Location], A.[item] 
                              ORDER BY A.[Serial]) as rn       
    FROM [TableA] A
    LEFT JOIN [TableB] B 
    ON  A.[Item] = B.[Item]
    AND A.[Serial] = B.[Serial]    
    AND B.Location <> 'N/A'
)
SELECT M.Item, M.Serial, COALESCE (M.Location, U.Location) as Location
FROM matchLocation M
LEFT JOIN unusedLocation U
  ON M.Location IS NULL
 AND M.Item = U.Item
 AND M.rn = U.rn
ORDER BY M.Item, M.Serial;
```

**OUTPUT**

First Picture is your output, Second is the `SELECT *`  so you see the partial result. This version you have to `partition by item` so rn reset to 1.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is great, thank you so much for the detailed answer. It almost does what I need it to. I've updated the question now that I've tried to implement this. I actually don't have an a.Sold column so I'm sorry for including that initially. Instead the way I know that they're sold in that table is that the rows are deleted from Table A. There turns out to be another column that I need to join from Table B called WHSerial as well.

Comment: Yeah, posting this has been a learning experience for me to explain myself better. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: at least take the time to update the rextester demo with the new data. Then save it and send me the link.

Comment: I updated the rextester demo with data that is more reflective to what I have. http://rextester.com/HZVHQ60086

Comment: Yes, that looks like it did it! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

How about we get you started on something that will get you most of the way there (The logic for naming the N/A racks we don't understand BUT here you go:
`Select A.*
,Case When B.Location Not Like 'N/A' Then B.Location
Else 'Rack1BinNA'
End As Location
From [Table A] A Left Join [Table B] B On A.Item = B.Item and A.Serial = B.Serial
Where A.Sold = 'No'`

Comment: With your updated comments you may change the Else 'Rack1Bin#' to Else 'Rack1Bin2' as it seems to be the default RackBin for N/A Location status.

Comment: This probably wasn't clear in my example but I actually have thousands of these locations and need to assign them to the serial numbers. I need a way for the query to see what the location is in Table B for unmatched serials between Table A & Table B and join them (hopefully that makes sense).

Comment: As others have stated, how do you correlate a RackBin number to N/A ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, which is probably why my question is unclear. N/A means that it no longer has a location in my warehouse because it has been sold. So things that I have in stock have a warehouse location of  RackXBinY (depending on where it has been put) whereas items that have shipped get a special location of 'N/A' because they're gone.

Comment: You could also change Like 'Rack1Bin*' to Not Like 'N/A'

Comment: How can you have a serial (36-0006) output that shows a location of RackBin2 when in table b it is N/A ? Does Table A have a location field you didn't display ?

Comment: Table A doesn't have the location column. That's actually why I have to link these two tables because I need the locations in Table B. The desired output shows that location because it is a location from one of the unmatched serials, like 36-0001. Since Table A doesn't have serial 36-0001 I'd like to utilize this location for 36-0006.

Comment: Since you have thousands of these locations, how do you pick one over the other from multiple serials that don't appear in Table A? That is the logic that is missing, if it is random - that can be coded, but it needs to be stated in your problem / question. We are almost there!

Comment: Yes, it is random. I'll edit my question to reflect that. Sorry for not being more clear in the first place.

Comment: Would your logic fill Table A's 'Serial 36-0008 No' fill the rack currently occupied by 'x45      36-0003    No       Rack1Bin2' ?

Comment: In this example I don't have a Serial 36-0008. Do you mean Serial 36-0007? If so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Can this not be solved using a LEFT OUTER JOIN with the item code and serial number? For example;

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Item = TableB.Item
AND TableA.Serial = TableB.Serial
```

You should then be able to select the desired columns from both tables.

Comment: The problem with that is it doesn't seem to replace the 'N/A' Locations in Table B with good locations.

Comment: Reading through the comments above I gain more of an understanding. One question though how is it determined when the for example 36-0003 is in Rack1Bin2 and 36-0004 is in Rack1Bin3?

Comment: Are the sold items Rack and Bin always going to match the first instance of an item with a similar serial numbers rack and bin?